# GCC and JVM auto parallel batch

Tags: java, c++, c, multithreading, gcc

Considering the following code snippets.

```
//C
int arr[1024];
void fill_array(){
  int len=sizeof(arr)/4;
  int res;
  for(int i=o;i<len;i++){
  res;//=some big operation
  arr[i]=res;
  }
}
//J
private int[] arr=new int[1024];
void fill_array(){
  int len=arr.length;
  int res;
  for(int i=o;i<len;i++){
  res;//=some big operation
  arr[i]=res;
  }
}
```

Assume each loop initializes only one index of `arr` and there is no any dependency on any other indexes. just like `arr[i]=i*2`.

I know that it should be run by GPU or at least paralleled.

**Question:**

Do either GCC compiler or JVM understand it(the loop) would be processed parallel and do it implicitly?
If yes, Is there any compile flag or something to turn this feature off or on?

Comment: Answer: No, not in the standard compilers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at least one experimental JVM out there, that's working on parallelizing such loops on the GPU  ([graal](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/graal/)). Haven't tried that myself, but I heard that it works for simple loops a few months ago - anyhow, certainly not feasible for any production code at this stage.

On the C side of things, I know that icc does in fact do auto parallelization but only for the CPU. Also it's pretty fickle and will "break" due to minor code or compiler version changes, so it's more a nice bonus if it works but you really shouldn't rely on it (or if you do, reserve quite a while for making sure it still works with every change and fiddle around with the code if it doesn't)